# how to use hashmap value to textview in android?

Tags: android, hashmap

i have one hashmap.hashmap have different value.
i want to display hashmap value in textview.

my code is

```
Iterator iterator = objJMap.keySet().iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) 
                {      String key = (String) iterator.next();
                    String value1 = objJMap.get(key);  }
```

how it display in textview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want display all hashmap value in a textview? textview set value in java code like this:
textview.setText(value1);

Answer (score 0):

You have to create run time text view in while loop and put the value in it.